# how to pass array values to any url in jquery without using php?

Tags: jquery, html

Hi Friends I am a beginner in jquery....I have a constraint that I
should not use php...so

```
var fields = new Array(

        $('#username').val(),
        $('#password').val(),
        $('#email').val(),
        $('#firstname').val() + ' ' + $('#lastname').val(),
        $('#age').val(),
        $('#gender').val(),
        $('#country').val()
    );
```

In the above coding , im getting all those values of the fields from
the form but the action attribute of the form is # but yet all those
values are obtained and thus putted inside the above array now to
connect to DB , how do I pass these values to any url....
I just have a difficulty I cannot specify in form action since I've
used # in it....Please help me
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Can't send anything to a server using action `#`. If not php, what server language will receive data? ALso much easier to use `serialize()` method on form to create your data to send

Comment: [http://api.jquery.com/serialize/](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 0):

One way is you can directly call [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function on form like this:

```
var str = $("form").serialize();
//check as per your need
```

It will serialize all elements and will give you in a string form that you can easily pass in url.

Another way is , you can call **.toString()** function on an array to convert it into string.

```
var field = new Array(1,2,3,5,6);
console.log(field.toString());
```